# Adding a class for select tag ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby

I want to add a class for the select tag.Like this.

```
<select class="phone_no">
```

I want the ruby equivalent of the above HTML line of code.

```
<%= select_tag(:id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>.') %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried: `<%= select_tag(:id, <option value="1">Lisbon</option>.', :class => "phone_no") %>`

Comment: see description here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: try this `<%= select_tag(:id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>.'.html_safe) %>`

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <%= select_tag(:id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>.',{}, { :class
 => 'phone_no' } ) %>
```

select helper takes two options hashes:,

- (1) one for select - in this case `{}`
- (2) and the second for `html options` - in this case `class`

Signature:

```
select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {}) public
```

(1) Select options available:

```
:multiple - If set to true the selection will allow multiple choices.

:disabled - If set to true, the user will not be able to use this input.

:include_blank - If set to true, an empty option will be create

:prompt - Create a prompt option with blank value and the text asking user to select something
```

(2) Any other key creates standard HTML attributes for the tag

more info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) in the `select_tag`, you shell pass `class` key-value pair via third option, i.e. shell do as follows. Also you may use `html_safe` method to pass a proper html as the second argument:

```
<%= select_tag( :id, <option value="1">Lisbon</option>.'.html_safe, :class => "phone_no" ) %>
```